# Refresh Configurationfile on change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I have got a configuration file with an minimumLevel for SeriLog.  Everything works as expected but the `reloadOnChange` property is not working

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(path: "xxx.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```

I am using below to read the configuration.  Can you please let me know what may be the issue ?

```
.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
```

Also I use an ServiceCollection with LoggerFactory as Singelton and I will create multiple instances of ILogger...

Greetz

Comment: can you post your code of how are you reading the JSON file ?

Comment: Its the first codeblock in my question

Comment: I mean, the complete line from 2nd code block ?

Comment: Problem resolved, the file need to be in the rootpath of the application...